# Get individual regions from TilemapCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get a list of each collider region from a `TilemapCollider2D`?  I see that `TilemapCollider2D` has a `shapeCount` property, but I don't see a way to get each shape's coordinates.

Comment: What would you like to use it for?

Comment: I'm trying to write an A* pathfinder class which is unit testable and configurable through code in the unit test.  Since I can't configure the collisions in a `TilemapCollider2D` in code (at least as far as I know), the pathfinder class has to get its collision information from a non-`TilemapCollider2D` class.  Then when the game is running in non unit test mode, I have to be able to get collision information out of the scene's `TilemapCollider2D` in order to construct the pathfinder.

Comment: Is it not possible to attach anything to the sprite parts used in the TileMap? If you could attach anything to them, you could give each of them a coordinate held in a script, then make a manager script to hold a collection of all coordinates and use it to make the pathfinding work.